# Publicly-accessible WebDAV

Tags: webdav

I'm working on a bit of WebDAV client capability in my code, and I'd to quickly test it without setting up my own WebDAV server.  Is there a publicly-accessible read-only WebDAV URL I could quickly try?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this test WebDAV server: https://www.dlp-test.com/webdav_pub/

You can even post files:

> All files uploaded to this site will be deleted at 2:00am UK time zone